# .htaccess redirect to subfolder, non-www to www and https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So I'm having this website which is stored inside public_html/www/. Some other domains are stored in -for example- public_html/test/. In public_html I have a .htaccess file with a LOT of redirects in it, which all apply to this website inside /www/ folder. Inside the /www/ folder I have another .htaccess (I don't really know why, my colleague did this and he left me with this without information). Since I have no idea how .htaccess exactly works, I have no idea what to do and in which file.

What I need to do is to redirect domain.nl to https://www.domain.nl (some folders should be excluded, like you can see in the code below - emailtemplates, paymentupdate, autocode, nieuwsbrieven, etc.) But domain.nl is stored inside public_html/www/ folder, so it also needs a redirect to the subfolder (which should not be visible in web browser).

At this moment, in the root .htaccess file is the following:

```
# Use HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.nl [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/emailtemplates
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/paymentupdate_ideal
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/autocode
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nieuwsbrieven
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bevestig-aanmelding-nieuwsbrief
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bevestig-afspraak
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/personal
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploadify
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Link to subfolder
# RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?www.domain.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?www.domain.nl$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ www/index.php?page=home [L]

# Non-www to www
#activate rewrite engine
#RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.nl
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Probably half of this code isn't even necessary, but I have absolutely no clue. The other .htaccess file, within the subfolder /www/, has the following text which I don't really understand (it contains more, but nothing relevant):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.nl/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

I'm sorry if I sound stupid. I've tried many things copied from internet, but unfortunately everything has its concequences, which results in other problems with our website (links that don't work anymore, such as). I think the reason it doesn't work all the time, is because it's stored in the subfolder and I don't know how to combine all those lines in one like it would work.

Can anybody help me explain how to fix this and what is going wrong at this moment? Because the website is now not redirecting to www. It's just redirecting to https which gives me a security error at this moment (because the SSL is stored on www.). SUPER thanks in advance!

Comment: The first two steps you really should start with: 1. get your colleague and ask for a proper documentation. Leaving work without is highly unprofessional. And no, there are _no_ valid excuses for such thing. 2. go and read some small tutorial about apache and `.htacess` style files so that you learn to use the tool you want to use.

Comment: Thanks, of course I should read some tutorials (and I'm gonna!), but that doesn't solve the problem within a day. My colleague is actually my ex-colleague and he doesn't respond to any contact I try. So unfortunately, that's no option. That's why I have to fix this myself, and I (and neither he) has the knowledge to. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was wrong order of the checks. First, I redirected to https://, but when I did not use www., it did not redirect to https://www OR it redirected to https://www.www. I fixed my problem by re-ordering my rules, like below:

```
# Non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Permanent redirect to https://
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/excluded_folder1/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/excluded_folder2/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/excluded_folder3/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Use subfolder for domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?www.domain.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?www.domain.nl$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ www/index.php?page=home [L]
```